# React Native App - Open with the google assistant and execute a command

Tags: javascript, react-native, dialogflow-es

I've been working on an app in react native - and have also build out an app in actions on google.

What I want to do is allow the user to invoke a command - from my react native android app - using the google assistant.

As an example:
"okay google, use jons app to make a note"

It would then open up the native android application - which would invoke a method to say "what is your note:" and at that point it would start speechrecognition - and when closed, take that and pass it on to dialogflow.

The premise behind this is allowing someone to use my voice assistant without directly integrating it on their device. Perhaps this is a flawed idea, or its not supported.

I found a sign up for this: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/

Which I was surprised is not yet available.

My question is simple - can i invoke explicit methods with a react native application from the google assistant?

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: I gave up on it when I was initially working on it but am revisiting it this quarter, hoping to find a reasonable solution.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress? I am trying to build something similar.